# Uniform convergence on punctured disc => analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on the punctured disc
>   $D'=\{z\in\mathbf{C}:0<|z|<1\}$. Suppose further that there are
>   functions $\{f_n(z)\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that are analytic on *all*  of
>   $D=\{z\in\mathbf{C}:|z|<1\}$ such that for any compact subset $K$ of
>   $D'$, $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly to $f(z)$ as $n\to\infty$. Show
>   that $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

I know that it suffices to show that $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, but I have no idea how to use the compact subsets $K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each $f_n$ is analytic on $D$, one can use the Cauchy's integral formula $$(\star) \qquad \forall z\in D, \quad f_n(z)=\dfrac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_r}\dfrac{f_n(w)}{w-z}dw $$ with $C_r=\{z\in\mathbb C \ : \ |z|=r\}$ and $|z|<r<1$.

Now, using the uniform convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ on the compact set $C_r$, we get that :

1. there exists $p\in \mathbb N$ such that $$\forall z\in C_r, \quad |f(z)-f_n(z)|\leq 1.$$
2. taking the limit in $(\star)$ : $\forall z\in D'$, $\forall r\in (|z|,1)$, $$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{2i\pi}\int_{C_r}\dfrac{f(w)}{w-z}dw.$$

Let us pick $r$ in $(0,1)$, then $\forall 0<|z|<\dfrac{r}{2}$, one has $$f(z)-f_n(z)=\dfrac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C_r}\dfrac{f(w)-f_n(w)}{w-z}dw.$$

So for any $0<|z|<\dfrac{r}{2}$, 
$$\begin{array}{rcl}|f(z)| & \leq &|f(z)-f_p(z)|+|f_p(z)| \\ & = & \left| \displaystyle \dfrac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{C_r}\dfrac{f(w)-f_p(w)}{w-z}dw \right| + |f_p(z)| \\ & \leq & \dfrac{1}{2\pi}\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{|f(re^{it})-f_p(re^{it})|}{|re^{it}-z|}rdt + |f_p(z)| \\ & \leq & 2 + |f_p(z)| \\ & \leq & 2 + M\end{array}$$
where $M$ is the maximum of $|f_p|$ on the compact set $\left\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|\leq \dfrac{r}{2}\right\}$.

Finally, $f$ is bounded around $0$ and thus it has a removable singularity at $z=0$.